# Posting array of images

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am posting array of images to the controller. There is weird issue which I couldn't understand. The issue is that when I debug the $request variable, it shows me the images array. But, when debug/access that specific array then it doesn't show images array. Following is the screenshot of the debugged variable.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploaded files must be accessed using the `file` method on the Request object:

```
$request->file('image');
```

Edit:

`$request->get()` is only used for GET and POST parameters.